# MySQL with multiple WHERE clauses

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a db with this info (example)

```
EMAIL                 COMING    
info@domain.com       google
test@example.net      google
text@example.net      yahoo
info@super.net        google
testing@foo.com       yahoo
testing@foo.com       google
```

I would extract ONLY value that are from "google" for example and not from "yahoo". So, in my SQL, i would read only

```
info@domain.com
```

and

```
info@super.net
```

because the other are FROM google && yahoo.

So, in code, a thing like

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE COMING = 'google' AND COMING != 'yahoo'
```

but obviously my code is wrong.

Could you help me? Thank you :)

Comment: from is a reserved word in mysql. Try `\`from\``, or better yet change the column name

Comment: Keep in mind that a normal `SELECT` with `WHERE` clause filters on a row-by-row basis and will not take other rows into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FROM` is a reserved keyword, you shouldn't use it in your table column names.

If you want to keep this keyword, you can use this request :

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE `FROM` = 'google'
AND email NOT IN (
    SELECT email 
    FROM mytable
    WHERE `FROM`='yahoo'
)
```

**edited following comments**

Comment: aside from syntax error. your query will not return as expected.

Comment: Can you add in something like `AND email NOT IN (SELECT email FROM mytable WHERE \`FROM\`='yahoo')` to exclude all those with `yahoo` matches?

Comment: Sorry, obviously my was only an example. Edited table... But i need help :)

Comment: how did this solve the problem? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79a9b/3

Comment: it will display `text@example.net` in the result which exist on both `coming`.

Comment: Wrong, we've got `test@example.net` and `text@example.com` (`s`/`x`)

Comment: @zessx how do you know it's a typo, oh yes if it was then why is `testing@foo.com` not in the result list?

Comment: Should I really explain a third time ? Take your time, correct this typo in your head, and read a bit carefully. Everything is working correctly, I can repeat myself, but I don't think this'll help you...

Answer (score 2):

see how a non-normalized table generates a poor performance query just to satisfy your needs,

```
SELECT a.*
FROM   TableName a
       INNER JOIN
      (
          SELECT substr
          FROM
          (
              SELECT email,
                     REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(email, LOCATE('@', email) + 1)),LOCATE('.', REVERSE(SUBSTRING(email, LOCATE('@', email) + 1)))+1)) substr,
                     coming
              FROM   tableName
          ) s
          GROUP BY substr
          HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT coming) = 1 AND
                 MAX(coming) IN ('yahoo','google')
      ) b ON a.email LIKE CONCAT('%@',b.substr,'.%')
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79a9b/1)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*added new record*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a974/5)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*with specific filtering on column `COMING`*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79a9b/2)

OUTPUT

```
╔═════════════════╦════════╗
║      EMAIL      ║ COMING ║
╠═════════════════╬════════╣
║ info@domain.com ║ google ║
║ info@super.net  ║ google ║
╚═════════════════╩════════╝
```

Comment: It won't display `text@example.net` and `test@example.com` in the result which doesn't exist on both coming.

Comment: according from your statement: "*..I would extract ONLY value that are from "google" for example and not from "yahoo". So, in my SQL, i would read only: `info@domain.com` and `info@super.net` because the other are FROM google && yahoo..."* -- why should `example` domain be on list when they are from google and from yahoo? perhaps you can update your question to satisfy with your accepted answer.

Comment: There's obviously a typo in the question, both should be `test@example.net` in the original example. You're just trying to solve a problem which has never been.

Comment: @zessx No, i'm just trying to help and i understood the question well. did you really understand the question? anywayy, your answer *seems* right because it's accepted `:)`

Comment: @zessx how do you know it's a typo, oh yes if it was then why is `testing@foo.com` not in the result list?